Get sourcedoc from document URL
I need to retrieve in Power Automate the source doc from document URL.
Example: https://domain.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/sites/test/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7BD700684F-DB56-4F7E-9CE1-C48BC4E83027%7D&file=Document%20.docx&action=default&mobileredirect=true&wdsle=0.
Does someone know? 'Get file properties' connector is not enough. Thank you!
